# In magento 2 mousehover on swatch disable non configurable option?

Tags: magento-2.2.5, swatches

In Magento2 default swatch function is we are select the color swatch disable the nonconfigurable option like size is not there.Like below image

http://prntscr.com/lh9jvl

how can i write the same functionality with mousehover on configurable swatches

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You will need to override the file located `swatch-renderer.js` at -

```
vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/web/js
```

You will need to look for the code -

```
_EventListener: function () {
```

This function triggers the onclick and does the function. In here you can change the lick to hover. I believe this will also effect on the product list page so you will have to see accordingly.